# How to differentiate bewteen begins with and contains in mongo Atlas using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-group, mongodb-atlas

I want to boost my score for begins with the case.
For example _ I have below two records.

```
HCL2% CRM
DETHRANAOL HCL CRM
```

I need a score of HCL2% CRM more than DETHRANAOL HCL CRM when searching with HCL for expected results.

I am trying regex `^HCL(.*)` so that it matches with HCL2% and then I will boost its score but this regex is not working in the mongo atlas query.

Can someone help?

Below is the query I am using.

```
db.compound.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      "index": "compoundSearchIndex",
      "compound": {
        "should": [
          {
            "autocomplete": {
              "query": [
                "HCL"
              ],
              "path": "name.en",
              "fuzzy": {
                "maxEdits": 2,
                "prefixLength": 1,
                "maxExpansions": 10
              }
            }
          },
           {
            "regex": {
              "query": [
                "HCL"
              ],
              "path": "name.en",
              "allowAnalyzedField": true,
              "score": {
                "boost": {
                  "value": 30
                }
              }    
            }
          },
          {
            "regex": {
              "query": [
                "HCL(.*)"
              ],
              "path": "name.en",
              "allowAnalyzedField": true,
              "score": {
                "boost": {
                  "value": 10
                }
              }    
            }
          },
          {
            "regex": {
              "query": [
                "(.*)HCL(.*)"
              ],
              "path": "name.en",
              "allowAnalyzedField": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "must": [
          {
            "equals": {
              "value": true,
              "path": "active"
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimumShouldMatch": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      
      "name": 1,
      
      "score": {
        $meta: "searchScore"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Would you show a sample doc and the query you are using?

Comment: I have added the query now in question itself.

Comment: {
            "regex": {
              "query": [
                "^HCL(.*)"
              ],
              "path": "name.en",
              "allowAnalyzedField": true,
              "score": {
                "boost": {
                  "value": 10
                }
              }    
            }
          }

Comment: This part of query is not boosting HCL2% CRM

Answer (score 0):

Using lucene.keyword analyzer instead of lucene.standard solved the issue.

Comment: By using lucene.keyword analyzer, search becomes case sensitive. In the above case boosting is as expected if we search with HCL but it is not as expected if we search with hcl. Any help here?